# Component builder for Joomla?

Tags: joomla, components

I'm trying to find a component builder for Joomla and I just found Marco's Component Maker, I'm wondering another one exist or not. I need some help, if anyone get help me that I'm very grateful.

Comment: recommending https://jc-creator.com/ with coupon NewUser2019 give 50%off

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are:

- [Joomla Component Generator](http://www.componentgenerator.com/)
- [joomla-component-creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/)
- [component creator](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/webbased-tools/7627)
- [joomla component maker](http://www.topshareware.com/joomla-component-maker/downloads/1.htm)
- [imaker](http://www.imaker.ir/en/makernew/)
- [Component Builder](https://www.vdm.io/joomla-component-builder)
- [JCCreator](https://jc-creator.com/)

Comment: you may thank me using the upvote arrow :)  (and of course accepting my answer)

Comment: All of these seem to use the "legacy" option. Any of them use the new MVC?

Comment: @AakilFernandes "Legacy classes" are still used in every Joomla component. There's a project for this year's Google Summer of Code that will move them to the 3.x classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can build basic component from this website

http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/

Answer (score 2):

Artisteer does not create or help create components, it makes templates. You may also want to check out Nooku, it's a complete development framework.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i use [Cook Self Service](http://www.j-cook.pro)

It's the best so far !!!
Easy to use, lot of functionalities, clean code, stand-olone...
I tried my first component after watching the video and I was fired up !!
After 1 hour learning how it is working, i built my first component to magage theater reservations, and it works like a charm.

I just try now to push the program out of its limits, but it's really amazing !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can build joomla component with table record edit/create/delete options + basic views

it is **free of cost**, you can create

- unlimited tables
- unlimited views
- no time limit for component hosting,
- with 'easy install' plugin you can directly updated changes in your
  installed component without downloading and installing. (just install
  your created component into your site once) all other changes can
  move directly to site with just one click
- You can use joomla inbuilt field, and preview of field is there

[image: You can use joomla inbuilt field, and preview of field is there]

[image]
http://www.developerextensions.com/index.php/joomla-component-creator

[image: Joomla component creator]

Answer (score 1):

I developed a component that you can install on your own Joomla website and build as many components as you like, with life time updates from github for free.

Check it out at the following URL

- https://github.com/vdm-io/Joomla-Component-Builder
- https://www.vdm.io/joomla-component-builder
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/component-builder

Have fun!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use alphaplug.com for creating components for Joomla.This is free of cost and doesn't need registration.Here's the link.
http://www.alphaplug.com/index.php/products/mvc-generator-online.html

Answer (score 0):

You can download extension [com_jacc](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/miscellaneous/development/jacc) (just another component creator) and install it in your joomla. Its very simple and powerful, just create tables in database and you are ready to go.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the best application: **Aristeer** (http://www.artisteer.com/).

The problem is the price. You can download the demo....

Comment: Artisteer creates templates not components. Besides, all the code underneath that is used to generate the front is a tangled mess if you ever need to customize their templates IMO.